# Forward HTTP requests to local Apache server behind router?

Tags: networking, apache2

I have an Apache server running on Ubuntu, and by default it is using name-based virtual hosts. For some reason I have to make my local server publicly accessible, but the problem is that I am running internet with WLAN router, and my WLAN router allows IP forwarding only to local IP addresses (not name-based hosts), so I can't forward HTTP request to my external IP address to e.g. localhost, but I can forward to, say, 192.168.x.x.

So my question is, can I make my Apache server run on some 192.168.x.x address to make it possible for router to forward HTTP requests to my local server.

Sorry for my amateur naive language, I am quite new to networking and stuff.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

`ip route` output:

`default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.101  metric 9`

Answer (score 2):

You can. Apache server represent himself with ip address from nic card. If you configure apache server to listen on port 80. Also to do port fw you must have:

- fix public ip address on wan side of router or ddns record for non fix public address
- fix local address on server aka 192.168.x.x
- do port fw on router from wan to lan for traffic on port 80
- check firewall, must allow traffic to port 80

If you have you domain you can make A record on dns server

```
yourdomain.com      A   your_public_ip_address
```

When some wish to see you site traffic flow will go on this way:

- enter a yourdomain.com in browser
- pc ask dns to resolve logical name to ip address
- pc send http req to ip address
- request travel via internet to your wan interface on router
- router pick traffic and forward to local ip, based on your rule
- server got http req on nic card
- server send answer to requester on same route

Comment: could you tell more about 'fix local address on server aka 192.168.x.x'. because my server listens only to name-based request that I register in /etc/apache2/sites-available and to 127.x.x.x (which are synonyms of localhost), but when I, say, telnet 192.168.x.x 80, then the request doesn't seem to be resolved by apache.

Comment: In apache you can set to appache to respond to one address or more.  in `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` you have `Listen 80`. That mean accept connection on port 80. After that you must set VirtualHost. If you config begin with   `<VirtualHost *:80>` and all other after / This mean that site is accessible for all ip addresses. On server with 2 nic card with 2 different ip addresses you can configure   <VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80> where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx represent ip from one nic card ....

Comment: No you don't telnet to localhost on port 80. Telnet to yourdomain.com on port 80. If you have only one site probably will work and `telnet localhost 80`

Comment: I got ``Listen 80`` in ports.conf. But setting <VirtualHost *:80> or more specifically <VirtualHost 192.168.x.x:80> doesn't bring anything, my 192.168.x.x request are still being timed out. As if 192.168.x.x request weren't local. 

By the way, I accidentally found a solution, since 192.168.0.101 works fine. The only mention of this address in my router settings is Assigned IP in DHCP client, but these entries are not editable

Comment: I think the solution would be setting correct routing. See my ``ip route`` output in edit.

Comment: Maybe is better to reconfigure you wlan from dhcp to manual and set `ip: 192.168.0.101` `nm: 255.255.255.0` `gw: 192.168.0.1` and some dns `dns: 8.8.8.8` DHCP can assign different ip to your server and port fw will not work

Comment: Yes it certainly would be. But here is another problem: when I set static IP to ``192.168.0.101``, I get error message: 'WAN IP address and LAN IP address cannot be in a same subnet. Please input another IP address.'. So I took a different one: ``192.168.37.238``, but then router denies port forwarding to this address: 'IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP'.

Comment: You set `ip: 192.168.0.99`. And port fw will be available.